# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":XPATH}

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

A while back, I created this script that downloads a file from a website into a specified folder using Selenium. It's been working fine for the past couple months, but after updating the ChromeDriver to 111.0.5563.64 (March 20, 2023), the code is no longer working, producing an error on line 58:

```
download_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, dwnicon)
```

The error says it can't locate the element (which I've asked for it to trace using XPATH) --

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ujcho\Desktop\Internal Weekly Bluesheet\HomicideReportCollector.py", line 58, in <module>
    download_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, dwnicon)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ujcho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 830, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ujcho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ujcho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='icon']/iron-icon"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=111.0.5563.65)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x0027DCE3]
        (No symbol) [0x002139D1]
        (No symbol) [0x00124DA8]
        (No symbol) [0x0015019F]
        (No symbol) [0x001503AB]
        (No symbol) [0x0017EE62]
        (No symbol) [0x0016AF14]
        (No symbol) [0x0017D57C]
        (No symbol) [0x0016ACC6]
        (No symbol) [0x00146F68]
        (No symbol) [0x001480CD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x004F3832+2506274]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00529794+2727300]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0052E36C+2746716]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00326690+617600]
        (No symbol) [0x0021C712]
        (No symbol) [0x00221FF8]
        (No symbol) [0x002220DB]
        (No symbol) [0x0022C63B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75D4FA29+25]
        DummyExport [0x6CC7CA11+42177]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DE7A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DE7A4E+238]
        (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

I have perused the Stack Overflow pages, and I couldn't find a solution to this issue. I've tried re-copying and re-pasting the XPATH for the Download icon to my script, but it's the same. I've also added a driver.implicitly_wait() command before it tries to find the element, but to no avail. Can anyone provide any insight on what may be the source of the problem? I wonder if it has to do with the recent ChromeDriver update. I've pasted the entire code of my script below. Thanks in advance.

```
    from requests import get
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import shutil
    import time
    from datetime import date
    import pandas as pd
    import os

#This script goes into the KCPD Crime Statistics Website and collects the Daily Homicide Analysis Report

#Helper Function to Cause Selenium to Wait to Find the Element Before Downloading
def waitFunction(driver, wait, text):
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, text)))
    except TimeoutException:
        return False

#Loading Webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : r'C:\Users\ujcho\Desktop\Internal Weekly Bluesheet\Daily KCPD Homicide Reports'}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument('--headless')
chromedriver = Service(r'C:\Users\ujcho\Desktop\Internal Weekly Bluesheet\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chromedriver, options=options)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = "https://www.kcpd.org/crime/crime-statistics/"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,5)

#Loading necessary variables
today_date = date.today().strftime('%m%d%Y')
print("Today is", today_date)

# driver.get(url)
driver.get(url)
link = "/html/body/main/div/div[2]/section/div/article/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/p/a"
waitFunction(driver,wait,link)
doclink = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, link)
doclink.click()


dwnicon = "//*[@id='icon']/iron-icon"
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
waitFunction(driver,wait,dwnicon)
download_icon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, dwnicon)
download_icon.click()

time.sleep(10)

alert = Alert(driver)
alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
presence_of_element_located
```

try element_to_be_clickable . have included a snippet of my own code below.

```
cookie = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[1]')))
```

Comment: the program is still struggling to locate the download button: 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='icon']/iron-icon"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=111.0.5563.65)`

Comment: I'm looking through the error, it looks like my current Chrome ver is at 111.0.5563.65, but the Chrome Driver I upgraded to is 111.0.5563.64... Could that be the source of the issue? But if that's the case, I don't get how the script is able to locate the link to the file, but not the download button. Link to Chrome ver issue: https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/Xa8FVQSQozM?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `Daily Homicide Analysis` link use the below `xpath`

```
//a[text()='Daily Homicide Analysis']
```

code:

```
doclink = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " //a[text()='Daily Homicide Analysis']")
doclink.click()
```

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at that XPATH syntax for the link to the Daily Homicide Analysis report? My XPATH (which I just copied and pasted after "Inspecting Element") for that link came out to be -- `/html/body/main/div/div[2]/section/div/article/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td/p/a` -- which works fine in the program. The issue is getting the program to locate the Download Button and subsequently click and initiate the download of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that shadow-root is now supported in Chrome and ChromeDriver.

The download button is nested in two #shadow-root nodes so you need to switch into them to get access to the download button.

```
shadow_host1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'downloads')
shadow_root1 = shadow_host1.shadow_root
shadow_host2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.ID, 'download')
shadow_root2 = shadow_host2.shadow_root
shadow_root2.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='icon']/iron-icon").click()
```

---

Some other suggestions:

1. Presence means the element is in the DOM, not necessarily ready to be interacted with. If you are waiting for something to be clickable use `EC.element_to_be_clickable()`, visible use `EC.visibility_of_element_located()`. Presence should rarely be used.
2. You are mixing `WebDriverWait` and implicit wait. According to the docs, Selenium lead, etc., `WebDriverWait` and implicit waits should not be used together. It can result in unpredictable behavior. It's strongly suggested that you use `WebDriverWait` whenever a wait is needed.
3. I simplified your locator for the "Daily Homicide Analysis" link. I know many people like to use copy XPath from the devtools but that produces XPaths (and CSS selectors) that are very brittle... likely to break with the smallest change to the page because the generally start at the HTML tag and have lots of indices, e.g. `div[3]` and so on.

You can simplify/rewrite your script to

```
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Daily Homicide Analysis']"))).click()
shadow_host1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'downloads')
shadow_root1 = shadow_host1.shadow_root
shadow_host2 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.ID, 'download')
shadow_root2 = shadow_host2.shadow_root
shadow_root2.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='icon']/iron-icon").click()

wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```